# Resize iframe pic to match the layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout, responsive

Is there any way to resize the picture on the right because the actual GIF is 500x500px and it is only showing 100x100px but at the same time keep the layout design like it is? Any help would be extremely apreciated!

What I have now (Demo w/ code): http://jsfiddle.net/dkfn482L/

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.t_container::after {
  clear: both;
}

.t_iframe {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.t_iframe iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.t_video {
  width: 64%;
  padding-top: 36%;
}

.t_image {
  width: 36%;
  padding-top: 36%;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {

  .t_iframe {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .t_video {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 36%;
  }

  .t_image {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="t_container">
  <div class="t_iframe t_video">
    <iframe frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/jNQXAC9IVRw"></iframe>
  </div>

  <div class="t_iframe t_image">
    <iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0436/5985/3990/files/ezgif.com-video-to-gif.gif?v=1597626410"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give the Iframe 'width' & 'height' attribute and set fixed value.

however, your CSS override the iframe natural width:

```
.t_image {
  width: 36%;
  padding-top: 36%;
}
```

Try to add `<img>` element to the iframe and give it a minimum values for height and width.

Comment: Gotcha! Bu after adding a fixed value for width and height the two iframes are no longer side by side... The gif jumps to below the video. Any thoughts?

Comment: so to understand you right, you want the image to be at the right side while the video is at the elft side?  how large is the picture allowed to be at maximum? Then the ebst solution would be to use a grid

Comment: try to use flexbox to get the two iframes position side by side.